# Flea hopping on triangle combinatorial solution

Tags: probability

So the problem is this: A flea hops about at random on the vertices of a triangle. Find the probability that after $n$ hops the flea is back where it started.

So let $X_n$ be the position of the flea at the $n$th hop. I want to find $P(X_n = 1 | X_0 = 1)$.

Now \begin{align} p_{1,1}(n) = P(X_n = 1 | X_0 = 1) &= \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^3 P(X_n = 1|X_1 = k, X_0 = 1)P(X_1 =k|X_0 = 1)  \\&=\sum_{k=1}^3 P(X_{n} = 1|X_1=k) P(X_1=k|X_0=1) \\&= \sum_{k=1}^3 P(X_{n-1}=1|X_0=k)P(X_1=k|X_0=1) \\&= \sum_{k=1}^3 p_{1,k}(n-1)p_{k,1}(1) \\& = \sum_{k_1,\cdots,k_{n-1}} p_{1,k_1}(1)p_{k_1,k_2}(1)\ldots p_{k_{n-1},1}(1)
\end{align}

So I just need to find the $(1,1)$ entry of $\begin{pmatrix}
0 &1/2&1/2\\
1/2 & 0 & 1/2\\
1/2 & 1/2 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}^n$ which after diagonalising and a lot of work turns out to be $\dfrac 1 3 \left(1 + \dfrac{(-1)^n}{2^{n-1}}\right)$.

Obviously there is a nicer combinatorial way of deriving this expression, but I'm rubbish at this kind of thing. Please help.

Please read the FULL question before marking as duplicate. Is this question going to get reopened then or shall I ask it again?

Comment: Does this help:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1450289/flea-on-a-triangle

Comment: @lulu No, it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a recursion for the situation.  Let $p_n$ be the probability that the flea is on the starting vertex after $n$ hops.

We have $p_0=1$ and $p_k=\frac12 (1-p_{k-1})$.  The reasoning is that if on step $k-1$ the flea is on the starting vertex, then flea can't be there on the $k$th hop; while if on step $k-1$ the flea is not on the starting vertex, it has a $.5$ probability of getting there on the next step.

You can then use induction to establish your result.

Comment: A lot better than my way though not exactly what I was looking for, since it is not directly combinatorial.